# Dynamic lazy instance variable memoization

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby we have 2 methods to get/set instance variables - `instance_variable_get` and `instance_variable_set`. Also in some cases it is a good practice to memoize instance variables:

```
@foo ||= 'bar'
```

So, I attempt to unite this 2 features since I need dynamic instance variables names:

```
iv = :@foo
instance_variable_set(iv, 'bar') unless instance_variable_get(iv)
```

I am not sure, but is there more elegant way to write this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> to lazy evaluate instance variables

This is not "lazy evaluation", this is "memoization".

> is there more elegant way to write this?

This reads more like the original expression (and is actually equivalent to it in behaviour):

```
instance_variable_get(:@foo) || instance_variable_set(:@foo, 'bar')
```